# Safari 5.1.1 SlowDown/Freeze

Tags: macos, safari

I am tired of how is working Safari on Lion. So the issue is : Safari can freeze at any moment , become unresponsive for some second then refresh page content. If i have more tabs opened , when switching through tabs , all web-pages are not visible (i mean that no content is visible on web-pages) then after some seconds page is reloaded, and everything is fine for a while. 
I have an extension (click-to-flash) , and these plug-ins installed : Flip4Mac Windows Media Plugin, iPhotoPhotocast, Java Applet Plug-in, QuickTime Plug-in 7.7.1, Shockwave Flash, Silverlight Plug-In (from Installed Plug-ins). I must mention that Safari even in this case is not crashing. Anyway it is not comfortable using Safari in this way. What can be the problem ???

Comment: If you turn off the extension and disable the plug-ins, does Safari still crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/20/stop-safari-auto-refreshing-web-pages-in-mac-os-x-lion/) (osxdaily.com) has solved my problem with Safari 5.1.1 (I had the same problems as yours)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: thx a lot , this solved problem